# mulesoft: ERROR: ramlParser: loadPath: loadApi: content/[object Object]: no such path

Tags: mule-studio, raml

I am using API Editor in Mulesoft and I am getting following error

```
ramlParser: loadPath: loadApi: content/[object Object}: no such path
```

It seems to be related to inclusions of libraries in main RAML such as:

```
 uses:
     myLibrary: !include libraries/myLibraryFile.raml
```

The libraries exist but still I am getting that error. Only if I remove the include the error goes.

Have any of you got same problem? How did you solve it?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using "uses:" you don't have to put "!include" only the name of the library and the path (without "!include").

See
[RAML- !include strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397718/raml-include-strange-behavior/42398663#42398663)
for a more detailed answer